# Two Export buttons to CSV in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, export-to-csv

I'm new to Ruby, I need to add a new button that export different attributes to csv.The old button exports all attributes of the collection.
I have this line in controller:

```
  respond_to :csv, only: :index
```

I have this in the html view:

```
 = link_to collection_path(format: :csv), tabindex: '-1'
          = fa_icon 'file-code-o', text: 'CSV', class: 'fa-fw'
```

and I have a file called `index.csv.slim`, its content:

```
= collection.to_csv
```

I have the `to_csv` method defined and it responds automatically to the export!
`http://localhost/records.csv`

How can I add a new button that responds to different method, should I add another file like `index.csv.slim`? how can I link them together ?
Or at least if I can pass a parameter to the `to_csv` ?
and :

```
= collection.to_csv(all)
```

and :

```
  def to_csv (all = true)
```

Note: we're using `inherited resources` and `Draper` gems.
so I don't have actions in controllers. 
and nothing there in routes file.

Note: using this [way](http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel)

Comment: Thew new CSV file is it at a different action or the same action, in the controller?

Comment: I don't have actions in controller,  we're using `inherited resources `.

Comment: The new export should respond to different attributes, so I need a new method `to_csv` but I don't understand how all of this in mapped automatically so I can add a new one easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution was to define the index action again:

```
  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.csv do
        @all = params[:all].present?
      end
      format.html { super }
    end
  end
```

and in the view:

```
= link_to collection_path(format: :csv, all: true), tabindex: '-1'

= link_to collection_path(format: :csv, all: false), tabindex: '-1'
```

and inside `index.csv.slim`

```
= collection.to_csv(@all)
```