# Rails Multiple CSV Export Buttons in Single View (i.e. Two or More)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, export-to-csv

I've followed Railscasts and the similar GoRails videos--searched SO for `[rails] [csv] export` to no avail. There's a similar but hard-to-follow question/answer called [Two Export Buttons to CSV in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37521492/two-export-buttons-to-csv-in-rails). I am able to add a single button to export my table records to csv (have chosen all records for this button).

**I want to add a *second* (or nth) button to my view page to export a subset of table records...e.g. `Event.where(country: some_country)` in addition to the current (working fine) button/download that exports all records of a model. I thought this would be a common use of a csv export.**

Here's what I have, working backwards:

**Events Index view**: I have a download button to export to CSV (added helper code for the glyph image)

```
<%= link_to glyph(:save), "events.csv", class: "btn btn-success" %>
```

If I want a second action, I need a different route than `events.csv`, right? So, I tried a new button changing "events.csv" to `@events_us.csv`.

**Events Controller**: have defined the 'what' and respond as all records (using ransack and will_paginate gems too):

```
def index
  @search = Event.ransack(params[:q])
  @events = @search.result.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 50)

  @events_all = Event.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # need to have html
    format.csv { send_data @events_all.to_csv, filename: "Events-#{Date.today}.csv" }
  end
end
```

Should I add a second `format.csv` in the `respond_to do...`? Tried that (i.e. defined a different instance variable like `@events_us = Event.where(country: "US")`, to no avail. Seems weird to have two `format.csv`s though. And, I get `No route matches [GET] "/@events_us.csv"`

I probably don't need to say much more, as I'm all kinds of lost on this one.

**Event Model**: use `all` scope, csv library, etc to organize the csv:

```
def self.to_csv
    column_names = Event.column_names.map(&:to_s) - %w[id created_at updated_at]

    CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
        csv << column_names
        all.each do |record|
            csv << record.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
        end
    end
end
```

If I have a second respond_to action in the controller, could I have a second method like `self.to_csv_us`?

```
def self.to_csv_us
    column_names = Event.column_names.map(&:to_s) - %w[id created_at updated_at]

    CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
        csv << column_names
        @events_us.each do |record|
            csv << record.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
        end
    end
end
```